# Which Open Source License require all derived work state that "This software is a fork of software A but is not related to A"?

Tags: open-source, licensing

So here's the situation:

I owns a simple open source project, let's call it Project A. It was forked by many contributors without changing the software name, they all call their fork Project A.

Many people who uses a fork of software A always seek for help from me, but I really don't know what was changed in the fork they use.

So, Is there any Open Source License explicitly requires all derived works should state their fork is different from the original work?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the GPL. Section 7 allows you to add additional terms

> Additional Terms.
>
> Notwithstanding any other provision of this License, for material you add to a covered work, you may (if authorized by the copyright holders of that material) supplement the terms of this License with terms:
>
> c) Prohibiting misrepresentation of the origin of that material, **or requiring that modified versions of such material be marked in reasonable ways as different from the original version**

All you need to do to use these additional terms is state them with the GPL you include (and mark it in a clear way, such that you're not advertising your work under the regular GPL).

If you want an example of such terms, [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/download/free-license-faq.html) uses the GPL with additional clauses, partly for this purpose.

Comment: The statement exactly met my requirement. But GPL is so evil that I cannot use in my project. Anyway I'll choose your answer as accepted. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a lot of choices (plus making your own) and I am not an IP lawyer (and don't even play one on TV), but [OSL3.0 a good choice](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0).

I think par. 4 speaks to your concern:

> 4) Exclusions From License Grant. Neither the names of Licensor, nor the names of any contributors to the Original Work, nor any of their trademarks or service marks, **may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this Original Work** without express prior permission of the Licensor.

Here's a [lengthy legal explanation](http://rosenlaw.com/OSL3.0-explained.htm#_Toc187293087), that I couldn't finish reading, as I fell asleep half-way through.

Please note that an advice from an attorney or a person who has corresponding legal credentials valid in your jurisdiction can not be substituted by my conclusions here. I am not such a person, just a person who's been around OSI stuff for a while and had to grapple with similar issues.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I don't own the name of my project as a "trademark" or "service mark". So it's not a very good choice :-)

Comment: @yegle, Actually, you don't have to own the trademark. By attaching a license you are the owner and the copyright holder ( described as `Licensor` above).

Comment: I think "names of Licensor" is my name ( yegle or whatever ), not the project name ( project A ), right?

Comment: @Yegle, yes it is. You are the Licensor